# Would redirect_to rather than send_file deliver better perceived rendering time when using Paperclip and S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have an app that lives in the Heroku ecosystem and it uses paperclip's S3 storage mechanism. Have any of you conducted performance tests of using `send_file` vs. `redirect_to` when sending file data via a controller action? To be specific:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @image = Image.find_by_name(params[:name])
    render :nothing => true, :status => 404 and return if missing_source(@image)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { send_file(@image.source.to_file.path,
                              :type => @image.source_content_type,
                              :disposition => 'inline') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @image }
    end
  end


  private

    def missing_source(image)
      image.nil? || !image.source.exists?
    end

end
```

My question is, would it be "better" to use

```
redirect_to @image.source.url
```

instead of

```
send_file(@image.source.to_file.path,
          :type => @image.source_content_type,
          :disposition => 'inline')
```

With `send_file`, it seems pclip requests the file from S3, saves the file temporarily on the local filesystem, then sends it to the browser. With `redirect_to`, the controller simply issues 3xx responses to the client.

Comment: Happy Saturday, hackers!

Comment: Some simple monkey-testing reveals that using the redirect tends to deliver better page rendering time, but I haven't take the time to prove this statistically. In addition, send_file can get some performance benefit by checking the if-modified-since header. I'm going to leave this question "unanswered" until I have time to try some stats against both approaches.

Comment: Do you need to perform some business logic before delivering the data, or not at all?

Answer (score 0):

well, the send_file defeats the whole purpose of using s3... you'll be using the app server to serve the file. Use the redirect

Comment: I disagree that "send_file defeats the purpose of using S3. Redirecting requests to S3 exposes the publicly available URL of that resource, whereas using send_file does not. This is important in cases where the application must perform some business logic before delivering the data.

Comment: well, it's obvious that's not the case here... if you need to process it, you need to process it. The OP is asking whether to use one or the other which makes it obvious he wont process it. Or that should have made been clearer in the question.

Comment: Don't you think there are cases where the benefits of S3 for asset storage are still valuable even though send_file may be used? Here are a few I can think of: no server management, no capacity planning, backups, filesystem and IO scalability.

Comment: yes, there might be such cases. Were you asking about a special case like that?